# Cannot assign requested address - bind(2) for "xyz.herokuapp.com" port 28159 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, puma, heroku-cli

I am uploading ROR application on Heroku but I am getting this error.

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/binder.rb:273:in 'initialize':
Cannot assign requested address - bind(2) for "xyz.herokuapp.com" port 28159 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)
```

I attached procfile and puma.rb code.

`Procfile`:

```
web: bundle exec puma -c config/puma.rb
release: bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

`puma.rb`:

```
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
threads threads_count, threads_count
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
```

I tried with puma 3.7 also but no luck 
Changed configuration of procfile too

On local its working fine but on heroku giving eror.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue when deploying a Rails 6.0 on Heroku.
I was using a environnement variable named HOST in order to provide to the [ActionDispatch::HostAuthorization](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-middleware) middleware the url of the heroku server because rails was asking for it in order to prevents against DNS rebinding and other Host header  attacks.
The name of the environment variable HOST was causing side effect when the heroku server was trying to start the server, the issue was discussed [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28500) and I I've used the same solution as [here](https://github.com/swrobel/meta-surf-forecast/commit/dfec199422d5ae5eaba02e44c4a1df6722545344).

1. heroku config:unset HOST
2. heroku config:set DOMAIN=youdomain.com
3. inside production.rb instead of `config.hosts << ENV['HOST']` use `config.hosts << ENV['DOMAIN']`
4. Add files on git, commit and deploy on heroku

Hope this will help.

Comment: This works. I initially set `HOST` to `default_url_options`. Change the variable name to `DEFAULT_URL_HOST` works. Thanks!